# Is there any function that calculates the rise time, overshoot, and settling time?

Tags: python, matlab, controls

I'm doing PID gain tuning for a DC motor
I gathered real data from the motor which involve the position according to time.
And i want to calculate the rise time, overshoot, and settling time from the data.
Is there any function in matlab or python which can do this?
Thank you!!

Comment: Please show some code we could help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the cases that you use the step command to extract the step-response characteristics of the system, the stepinfo command calculates the rise time, overshoot, and settling time, and so on. I don't know whether it is applicable in the data case or not but you can test it?